# ORM/Library for asynchron save & update operations?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

### Describtion

Im working on a little java game server and i need to save & update my game entities in an asynchron way, without blocking the main thread. Till now i was using hibernate, but for some reason hibernate does not like multithreaded save & update operations and throws dozends of different exception ( See my last 10 questions... those are all hibernate multithreading related ).

Im honestly sick of those hibernate issues. I just want some ORM or library that allows me to save, load and update my pojos in an easy, async way... without hunting solutions for weeks or months.

### Question

What ORM or library could a java game use for non blocking saving, updating and loading operations ? I prefer SQL databases, but nosql probably should also work fine.

Im glad for any help i can get on this topic :)

Comment: Sorry, library recommendations are off-topic

Comment: @Michael Since when ? I literally saw dozends of similar questions... either libs, frameworks, recommendations...

Comment: Oh, probably for the past 10 years.

Comment: @Michael Weird and why ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic item #4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate works fine for me executed in a Scheduler. It just doesn't like when you load an entity and try to persist changes outside of the current request at a much later time - there is also a lot of uncertainty to handle here, as the entity isn't synced with the database anymore.

Cannot you collect your changes in some kind of data objects, and later when persisting do the whole loop: load from repository, update with data from data objects, and then persist? There shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: Thanks ! Well that would probably work, but it requires a lot of select statements... i think thats called a merge operation, right ? Not sure about the n+1 issue here, especially for relations

Comment: Mh yes you would probably have more selects, but as they are generally much cheaper then the updates anyway, I would say it's not much an issue. After collecting your data you know which entitys you are going to update, so you use repository.findAllById(listOfIds) and catch them all at once. Then you merge in your changes and call repository.saveAll(listOfEntities). Not sure if I would use some of the "magic" merge stuff, you probably know what changes are happening, so you could collect them in some HashMap and update the entities one by one.

Comment: Relations are a separate topic, right. I would always use LAZY initialization and probably do extra loops as well. Maybe this article could help you https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-performance-issues/